# Можно ли "отвязать" child процесс от родителя

Tags: node.js

Приветствую.

Есть небольшое приложение на node.js работающее в фоне. Из этого приложения запускаются другие процессы следующим образом:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
exec('process.exe');
```

Все работает, все запускается. Но, вот проблема: если закрыть основное приложение, то запущенные таким образом процессы тоже закрываются. Можно ли как-то этого избежать?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно при создании дочернего процесса ставить параметр `detached` в значение `true`.
Смотрите подробнее [в документации](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached).